# Express.js cookies shown as undefined in production website but works on localhost

Tags: node.js, express, cookies

These are the inputs and declarations

```
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const bodyparser = require("body-parser");
const path = require('path');
const axios = require("axios");
var admin = require("firebase-admin");
const { google } = require('googleapis');
const app = express();

const fs = require('fs');
var credentials = require("./config.json");

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "/views"));
app.use(cookieParser());
```

This is how I'm setting and retrieving the cookies

```
res.cookie('email', googleUser.email);

app.get("/onboarding", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    console.log("These are the cookies", req.cookies);
    res.render("onboarding_second");
  } catch(error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
});
```

This works perfectly fine when I try it locally, but when I try it on my hosted website it shows undefined when I try to log it.

Also, in the hosted website I can see the cookie getting created when I inspect it. I suspect it is an issue on the server side where I try logging the cookies.

Any ideas how I could fix this?